# How to test for 'Limited Access' to the Internet

Tags: java, android, connection

I have an Android Application that has to fetch an XML file from a particular URL.

To do this, I first check if an internet connection is available and if so, I download the file. This works fine.

The issue happens when I use my app in a network where users can connect to the internet but need to provide a username and password before they can access any page i.e. Limited Access.

How can I test for Limited Access to the network?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine that the user has a fully functioning network connection try to open a web link programmatically in background if you get a success status then internet connection is available else  user has limited access.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821825/detecting-limited-network-connectivity-in-android) may help you.Have a look