# How to detect limited internet connectivity in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, exception, xmlhttprequest

I am working on an app that is basically dependent on services. Issue is when internet is limited then app crash because of jason response is {} so if we try to get object or array at  0 index it crashes and try catch block is not catching the exception so i want to check limited connectivity. I'm checking it while sending post request to server but in that case HttpResponce object take almost 1 to 2 min so i want to improve user experience what should i do any suggestion please .

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeoutConnection = 1000;
int timeoutSocket = 1000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
```

this time out is not working i guess conection is not establish that is the reason.
Any one can please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: ping google from your android app to check network reachability first then try your code

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821825/detecting-limited-network-connectivity-in-android

Comment: @Illegal Argument google is not working in china

Comment: try baidu then it works there

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your http call asynchrounous. In that way you execute anything until your http call finishes. Or simply check null value or empty of your json.

Comment: Things is that Httpresponce take almost 1 to 2 sec its a big delay.